# Parse.initialize causes android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException exception on some devices

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, networkonmainthread

I've started using Parse recently, and I'm calling `Parse.initialize` from my applications main activity `onCreate` method. On my devices it works properly, but some users who tried it are getting `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` when `Parse.initialize` is called. See strack trace here: http://crashes.to/s/fbe1eda87a0

I've tried moving the Parse initialization code to `AsyncTask`, so  it won't run on the main UI thread; but this resulted in the app crashing, because another part of the Parse SDK was trying to do an operation but the SDK wasn't initialized yet (I have no control over that part).

I've moved the call to `Parse.initialize` to `Application.onCreate` in the meantime, but not sure how that supposed to be better.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and knows how to solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: "but not sure how that supposed to be better" -- that is not better. As the answer that Apoorv links to points out, you need to move your network I/O to a background thread.

Comment: I know what the exception means and I'm aware of how usually one solves this, but in this case it just caused another issue. This is a Parse specific question, not a general one (I've updated it with additional information).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so moving `Parse.initialize` into the `Application.onCreate` solved the issue.